# target goal pose is not stable when using navigation2

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am newbie in ROS using quadruped robot.

I use Unitree A1 and ROS2 navigation package for human tracking in isaac sim simulator.

An obstacle is placed between the robot and the person, and the robot uses a vision module to try to detect the person's location and its depth information using RGBD camera.

When there are no obstacles, the A1 uses the vision module to recognize the location and depth of the target and follow it well.

However, when there is an obstacle between A1 and a person, A1 initially recognizes the location and depth of the target using the vision module and tries to follow it well, but when A1 turns, the target pose bounces in a strange direction.

In this case, how can I solve this problem?

[A1 navigation fail](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qbtITkpc03clMA9UUpDoMgobglDByb5v/view?usp=share_link)

Above is the link to the captured video, since I couldn't find a way to upload a video directly to a post.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413459/target-goal-pose-is-not-stable-when-using-navigation2/) by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2023-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm understanding your question properly, you saying that your vision system isn't properly detecting the person vs the obstacle properly so the goal pose isn't good? If so, that has nothing to do with Nav2, that's on your vision system to send the right goal to the stack. You need to fix the vision system - it seem that Nav2 is fine.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on 2023-03-16**:
thank you for the answer! Yes you are right. I had no choice but to lower the fps of the vision module, so the path kept changing as the location of the target on the camera frame kept changing. Then, I want to ask one more question, if the path keeps changing as above and if I want to slow down the degree of change, should I change the frequency of the planner, which acts as a global planner?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-03-16**:
Yes, or modify the behavior tree to do event-based replanning instead of regular frequency replanning. There are example BTs of that in the stack already, but may obviously be further customized for your application.

**Comment by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on 2023-03-17**:
Thank you for your comments! I find the behavior tree examples in the navigation2 stack! Hope you have a good day :)